# tinymce only readable in jquery ui dialog

Tags: tinymce, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi i'm using tinymce in a jquery ui dialog.
But is only readable
why?

How can i fix it?

thanks

Comment: Are you initializing it *before* or after you display the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.
i have to do the init of the tinymce on the dialog's textarea after the open event of it
and destroy it on beforeClose event.

Comment: Could you add an example of how you did this please?